# Global exception handler for MVVM Light application

Tags: wpf, exception, mvvm-light

I'm trying to create a simple global exception handler in a WPF application that is build with the MVVM Light Toolkit, but I'm having a hard time making it work.

The thing is that an exception risen in a view model will not be caught in the App's UnhandledException handler, even though I register a listener for both the Dispatcher and the AppDomain like this:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += DomainUnhandledException;
   DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
}

private void DomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
   var exception = unhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject as Exception;
   ShowExceptionMessage(exception);
}
private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   ShowExceptionMessage(e.Exception);
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

I found [this blog post](http://codifying.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/silverlight-unhandled-exception-and-mvvm-light/) that describes the problem spot on, with the solution described with this code snipped for view models:

```
// Throw the exception in the UI thread.
App.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { throw new MyException(); });
```

However, I would like all exceptions to bubble up to the global exception handler, not only the ones that I throw myself in the VM.

So the question is: Is it somehow possible to re-throw exceptions from other threads into the UI thread in one place?

**Update**: Added more detailed code for the App's event handler setup.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was obviously not investigating this problem enough before asking the question. The exception that I tested with is actually thrown in a VM constructor. Unity is used for DI, so the question should maybe be, how to handle exceptions in constructors on objects that are created by unity?

Comment: To explain a bit further, this is how the VMs are bound to the view's DataContext: `DataContext="{Binding MyVm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`. Locator is exposing the following property: `public MyViewModel MyVm { get { return unityContrainer.Resolve<MyViewModel>(); } }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I figure this out now.

The problem is due to the fact that WPF suppresses exceptions thrown in a view's databinding, and because my view model is databound to the view's DataContext (through a property in my *ViewModelLocator* utilizing unity dependency injector) any exceptions in the construction of the view model will be swallowed.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978887/why-does-wpf-databinding-swallow-exceptions) for more info.

So I suppose I just have to make sure that nothing important for the application's ability to function correctly should happen in the constructor.

Comment: They are only suppressed once the view is already visible. If you try to show a view and the view model has exceptions thrown by its bound properties (Assuming you already set the data context before calling show ) you will not be able to open the window

Answer (score 1):

The “global” exception handling events for WPF and Windows Forms applications (Application.DispatcherUnhandledException and Application.ThreadException) fire only for exceptions thrown on the main UI thread. You still must handle exceptions on worker threads manually.

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException fires on any unhandled exception, but provides no means of preventing the application from shutting down afterward.

- Maybe check also Thread Pooling “divide-and-conquer” style.
- TPL

[How do I invoke a method on the UI thread when using the TPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324123/how-do-i-invoke-a-method-on-the-ui-thread-when-using-the-tpl)

Comment: Yes, I know that the DispatcherUnhandledException is for UI thread exceptions and AppDomain's UnhandledException for any unhandled exception. The thing is that none of them catches any exception that I raise in a command handler in the VM. Does MVVM Light have some sort of "global exception handler" for its threads, or do I have to wrap all command handlers in a try-catch block?

Comment: Actually, if I throw an exception in a data bound command it will indeed bubble up to the Dispatcher's exception handler. Please see my comment on the question.